# Flex Mobile iPad - Softkeyboard still showing up on textInput Component

Tags: ipad, apache-flex, mobile, android-softkeyboard

I am creating an iPad app in which I have a textInput component that when it is in focus is suppose to call a callout with a spinner in it.  The problem is that the softkeyboard is showing up every time I touch the textInput component.  I have tried everything I could find which includes the following:

```
    private function onActivating(event:SoftKeyboardEvent):void 
    {
       event.preventDefault();
    }           

    <s:TextInput softKeyboardActivating="onActivating(event)" />
```

and

```
    <s:TextInput needsSoftKeyboard = "False"/>
```

Both of these examples are still having the softkeyboard show up.

Comment: I don't quite understand the necessity of a `TextInput` if you don't want to enter text in the first place...

Comment: I am using it to display text that the user chooses in the callout.

Comment: So why don't you just use a simple label then, cause that's what `Label`s are made for.

Comment: I was just talking to the person I am working on this with and we were just talking about that.  The only problem is we want the user to know that is where they should click.  That is why we were working with TextInput in the first place.  We have multiple spots where they have to edit text using callouts so we dont want them to get confused.  If there is no other way around this, this is the route we are going to go.

Comment: Instead of fiddling around with the wrong component for this task (the `TextInput`), I'd rather go with a `Label` and a suitable skin that makes the user understand that he's supposed to click it in order to change its value.

Comment: If you still feel you need the `TextInput`, you can try to change the skin (Adobe messed it up with Flex4.6) to `spark.skins.mobile.textinputskin`. That might help, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Yeah I will give that a shot, the only problem I have been having with Skins is that we can only get the callout to show up once.  If we try to click on it a second time the callout doesnt show up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply disable the TextInput and change the styles so it doesn't look disabled? Touch events may not trigger though but short of styling a label [as suggested above] you'll have to do some trickery one way or another.

Comment: Yeah we did try to disable the TextInput and when we did that the Touch Events did not trigger.  We ended up just using a calloutButton, and have the label for the button show the text we want to show.  Thanks.